# Xcode - SIGABRT error ONLY on MY mac

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sigabrt

I get a SIGABRT error in my Xcode-project. The strange thing is, that on another mac the project runs without an error.

I allready did:

- clean the project
- restarted Xcode and the mac
- deleted the app files from simulator

And on both mac's is the same Xcode version.

Have anyone a spontaneous advice for me? :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the BaseSDK is set to the latest iOS version or not for both macs?